# Signature Invalid Error

Tags: magento

```
$customers  = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $firstName)
```

On adding this function in Rest.php it returns signature invalid error.
Does it needs mapping in xml file??

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding ->load().

```
$customers  = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', $firstName)->load();
```

The reason being that Magento does not do anything with that object until you try to use it, like do a foreach on the results.  By calling load() you are forcing it to fully load the object and get the results.

Comment: Thanks for your response,but in function validateSignature() in file server.php the signature created for validation and for request contradicts,which makes problem.please explain where the signature is created and how??

Answer (score 0):

SOAP and REST menu found here
[image]

I would suggest creating the role first.  Then create the user.

Once that is setup, your application can communicate based on the role you provided.

I hope this helps. If you already setup the role and user, then verify your username and  api key are correct in your application.

In case you did not know API Key is the equivalent to a password.

Once that is setup you can access your site using some code similar to this API call:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://whatever.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'myusername', 'apiKey' => 'mypassword'));
$result = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo((object)array('sessionId' => $sessionId->result, 'customerId' => '220769'));
print_r($result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but this has been done earlier itself but no luck.Only advanced rest client only giving such error in rest client gives the output.so its fine.